# Send certain emails to RSS feed

Tags: gmail, rss

I get emails (Gmail) for premium members only (Business of fashion) and I would rather read them in an RSS feed. How do I redirect them to my RSS feed (Feedly)

Comment: [How to See Gmail Emails in an RSS Reader](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-get-gmail-notifications-in-your-rss-feed-reader-1172050)

Comment: If only the Internet were this data friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Zapier (a Web automation service) to build a link between Gmail and RSS.

Comment: How do you go about doing this?  Just saying "use x" is not as useful as saying how to use it to perform the needed task. Consider reading [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)